# How to cope with zero/null values in data sets?

Tags: regression

I have a dataset that will be used to estimate future footfall and purchases within a number of stores. The data set covers about 3 years of footfall for various stores. When going through the data, I noticed that on some days, the different stores did not enter the footfall for the store. This is throwing off the analysis and the regression models that are being created from the data.

From a statistical perspective, what is the best way to cope with these zero/null values? Would it be correct to ignore the entries that have a zero/null value in the footfall, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try:

1. Ignore the missing values (e.g., drop them)
2. Impute the missing values as the mean/median/mode for the respective column
3. Use something like k-NN to impute the missing values e.g., https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html
4. Use something more advanced like Gaussian Copula Methods to estimate and impute the missing data https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Florian_Hollenbach/publication/267760010_Fast_Easy_Imputation_of_Missing_Social_Science_Data/links/54e63f520cf277664ff4ccfc/Fast-Easy-Imputation-of-Missing-Social-Science-Data.pdf

Comment: Thanks. KNN looks like the best approach, followed by dropping the values.